# Angular ReactiveForms - nested FormGroup within FormArray (no control found)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, frontend

I have the following formarray (inside a parent: formgroup):

```
someArray: this.fb.array([
{
   someGroup: this.fb.group(
   {name: 'value', type: 'value2;}
   )
}
```

My html looks as follows:

```
<fieldset formArrayName="someArray">
  <div *ngFor="let someValue of parents.controls.someArray.controls; let x = index" >

    <div [formGroupName]="x">
     <fieldset formGroupName="someGroup">
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot find control at someArray -> 0 > someGroup
```

I would expect that at index 0 in someArray, there is a formGroup somegorup therefore I can add a fieldset in the html for it. However this isn't the case. Can somebody explain why?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you created FormArray of one FormControl with the value:

```
{
   someGroup: this.fb.group(
     {name: 'value', type: 'value2}
   )
}
```

What you're looking for is:

```
someArray: this.fb.array([
   this.fb.group({
      someGroup: this.fb.group(
        { name: 'value', type: 'value2' }
      )
   })
])
```

Notice `this.fb.group` when constructing element for FormArray.

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/goRdkdBeRI6Ovsin0zLc)**